# How to make request to Kubernetes service?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

When I am trying to send an HTTP request from one pod to another pod within my cluster, how do I target it? By the cluster IP, service IP, serivce name? I can not seem to find any documentation on this even though it seems like such a big part. Any knowledge would help. Thanks!

Comment: [Connecting Applications with Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/) in the Kubernetes documentation seems relevant.  In general you can use the destination service name as a DNS name.

Answer (score 8):

[DNS for Services and Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) should help you here.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myservice
  namespace: mynamespace
spec:
  selector:
    name: myapp
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
```

Lets say you have a service defined as such and you are trying to call the service from the same namespace. You can call `http://myservice.svc.cluster.local:80`. If you want to call the service from another namespace you can use `http://myservice.mynamespace.svc.cluster.local:80`

Answer (score 3):

As @[David Maze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10008173/david-maze) mentioned, 
you can find more information about:

- ["Connecting Applications with Services and Exposing the Service"](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/),
- ["testing and debugging"](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/),
- ["Publishing services and service types"](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types)

Shortly:

Please exec into your pod:

```
kubectl exec -it <your_pod> -- /bin/bash
```

perform:

```
nslookup <your_service>
```

In that way you can check if your service is working using DNS (assuming your service is working in default namespace) you should see:

```
<your_service>.default.svc.cluster.local
```

than you can check:

```
curl http://<your_service>
or
curl http://<your_service>.default.svc.cluster.local
```